# CSS: Put a div-container at the bottom on a div-container

Tags: html, css

My intention is to place a div-container inside a div-container, but it isn't working atm. My div-container which should be placed at the bottom sticks to the bottom of the whole page.

```css
.info-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.info-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 470px;
  background: url('../img/infoheader.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: auto auto;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.info-header h3 {
  font-family: 'SignPanter', sans-serif !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #747474;
  text-align: center;
}

div.info-bottom-text:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #747474;
}

.info-bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-container">
  <div class="info-header">
    <div class="info-header-text">
      <h3>Los Santos International Airport</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info-bottom">
    ss
    <div class="info-bottom-text">
      sss
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Between the header and footer of the div should be a content div which isn't implemented yet.

Would be nice if someone can help me with my issue!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to wrap everything inside of a relatively-positioned element that is a direct child of the outer `.info-container`.

This can be seen in the following, in which I've created the class `info-wrapper` with the simple rule `position: relative`.

```css
.info-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.info-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 470px;
  background: url('../img/infoheader.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: auto auto;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.info-header h3 {
  font-family: 'SignPanter', sans-serif !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #747474;
  text-align: center;
}

div.info-bottom-text:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #747474;
}

.info-bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.info-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-container">
  <div class="info-wrapper">
    <div class="info-header">
      <div class="info-header-text">
        <h3>Los Santos International Airport</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-bottom">
      ss
      <div class="info-bottom-text">
        sss
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

set for outer div set stlye as

```
position: relative;
```

for the inner div set style as

```
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`info-container` should have `position: relative`

```
.info-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 450px;
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 38px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
  background-color: yellow;
}

div.info-header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 470px;
  background: url('../img/infoheader.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: auto auto;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.info-header h3 {
  font-family: 'SignPanter', sans-serif !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #747474;
  text-align: center;
}

div.info-bottom-text:hover {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #747474;
}

.info-bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```